# Show contents of .csv file in Markdown

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, markdown

I have a C# solution that contains unit tests automatically generated from a .csv file via text templates.

The .csv file is a nice table for any team member to refer to, and serves as living documentation of the system.

We're running TFS 2015 and I understand that Markdown can be used in conjunction to provide clear system documentation.

Is it possible to use Markdown to display the contents of a .csv file (stored on the TFS server) within a table? So that if the .csv file is edited, the Markdown page reflects this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, it's impossible. Detail info about Markdown page in TFS, please refer this tutorial: [Markdown guidance](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/reference/markdown-guidance)

I have created a uservoice for you, you can vote up for it and TFS admin will kindly review the suggestion.

> **Show contents of .csv file in Markdown**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17749084-show-contents-of-csv-file-in-markdown

Comment: visualstudio.uservoice.com link is broken

Comment: @MuhammadHarisAltaf Yes, we now moved to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea Developer community site for feature page.

Comment: The link does not lead to the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

you can use dbeaver that will create a markdown table of your query result

[image]

click on export data and than:

[image]

`next` `next`

and in `Output` section check Copy to clipboard

[image]

click `next` and at the end click `proceed`

[image]

now you can copy your markdown text saved in your clipboard (this is the place where the system store data once you hit CTRL+C) insiede your markdown file